# Getting the Input of various text fields into a label and saving that as a file

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to write a program that gathers the input from a bunch of Text widgets and then put it into another Text Widget, which then the user may safe on their local device
. That approach quickly failed completely for me so I switched to using a Label instead. The Label works and I can save the input into it, but the saveFile function saves empty files.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter as ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

    
class demo:
#I created this to test what I can do with classes. It definetly isn't the best approach so I may overhaul it at one point
#in the future once I gained more experience to do so, but as it stands right now its my best efford.

    def __init__(self, window_body):
        root.title("Test")
    
            
        main_frame = Frame(window_body)
        main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
        my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame,orient='vertical', command=my_canvas.yview)
        my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill='y')

        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
        second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
        my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame,anchor="nw")
#Adds a Frame, to which a Canvas and then a second frame gets attached.
#This second frame will be used for attaching the Labels and alike
#To the Window
        def saveFile():
            file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir="C:\\Users\\Cakow\\PycharmProjects\\Main",
                                    defaultextension='.txt',
                                    filetypes=[
                                        ("Text file",".txt"),
                                        ("HTML file", ".html"),
                                        ("All files", ".*"),
                                    ])
            if file is None:
                return
            filetext = str(self.vollständigf.get(1.0,END)
            file.write(filetext)
            file.close()



 
        self.refresh= Button(second_frame, bg="white", text="Arbeitszeugnis erstellen", command=lambda: get_input())
        self.refresh.place(x=355,y=1600)
        self.save = Button(second_frame, bg="white", text="Speichern", command=lambda: saveFile())
        self.save.place(x=355,y=1630)
        
        #menubar = tk.Menu(root)
        #root.configure(menu=menubar)
        #fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
        #menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        #fileMenu.add_command(label="save",command=saveFile)    


        
        def get_input():
            self.titelfm=self.titelf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.namefm = self.namef.get('1.0',"end")
            self.nnamefm = self.nnamef.get('1.0',"end")
            self.gatumfm = self.gatumf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.gortfm = self.gortf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.posfm = self.posf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.bereichfm = self.bereichf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.eintfm = self.eintf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.austfm = self.austf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.einleitungsfm = self.einleitungsf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.firmenbeschreibungfm = self.firmenbeschreibungf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.tati1m = self.tati1.get('1.0',"end")
            self.tati2m = self.tati2.get('1.0',"end")
            self.fachwissenfm = self.fachwissenf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.leistungsbereitschaftfm = self.fachwissenf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.arbeitsweisefm = self.arbeitsweisef.get('1.0',"end")
            self.arbeitsqualitätfm = self.arbeitsqualitätf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.belastungsfähigkeitfm = self.belastungsfähigkeitf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.arbeitsweisefm = self.arbeitsweisef.get('1.0',"end")
            self.arbeitsqualitätfm = self.arbeitsqualitätf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.belastungsfähigkeitfm = self.belastungsfähigkeitf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.führungsstilfm = self.führungsstilf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.gesamturteilfm = self.gesamturteilf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.sozialesfm = self.sozialesf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.austfm = self.austf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.abschfm = self.abschf.get('1.0',"end")
            self.sonstigesfm = self.sonstigesf.get('1.0',"end") 
            self.vollständigf.config(text=self.titelfm + self.namefm + self.nnamefm + self.gatumfm + self.gortfm + 
                                        self.posfm + self.bereichfm + self.eintfm + self.austfm + 
                                        self.einleitungsfm + self.firmenbeschreibungfm + self.tati1m + self.tati2m + self.fachwissenfm + 
                                        self.leistungsbereitschaftfm + self.arbeitsweisefm + self.arbeitsqualitätfm + 
                                        self.belastungsfähigkeitfm + self.führungsstilfm + self.gesamturteilfm +
                                        self.sozialesfm + self.austfm + self.abschfm + self.sonstigesfm)
    
#This was a attempt at getting the Input from the other Labels, putting them into Variables and then putting them into
#The last Label. It works for the most parts without problems but I have yet to figure out how to allow for changing the aligment of them.



        self.Mitarbeiter= Label(second_frame,text="Angaben zum Mitarbeiter",font = "Times 15  bold")
        self.Mitarbeiter.place(x=15,y=15)
        self.anrede = Label(second_frame,font=("Times"),text=("Anrede:"))
        self.anrede.place(x=15,y=45)
        self.OptionList = ["Herr",
                        "Frau",
                        "Sonstige"]
        variable = tk.StringVar(second_frame)
        variable.set(self.OptionList[0])
        opt = tk.OptionMenu(second_frame, variable, *self.OptionList)
        opt.config(width=5,height=1, font=('times', 12))
        opt.place(x=15,y=65)
        
        
        self.titel = Label(second_frame,font=("Times"),text="Titel:")
        self.titel.place(x=105,y=45)
        self.titelf = Text(second_frame,height=1,width=10)
        self.titelf.place(x=105,y=65)
        self.titelfm = text="DEFAULT TITLE TEXT"
        
        self.name = Label(second_frame,font="Times",text="Vorname:")
        self.name.place(x=205,y=45)
        self.namef = Text(second_frame,height=1,width=10)
        self.namef.place(x=205,y=65)
        self.namefm = text="DEFAULT VORNAME TEXT"
        self.nname = Label(second_frame, font=("Times"), text="Nachname:")
        self.nname.place(x=305,y=45)
        self.nnamef = Text(second_frame, height=1, width=10)
        self.nnamef.place(x=305,y=65)
        self.nnamefm = text="DEFAULT NACHNAME TEXT"
        
        self.gatum = Label(second_frame, font=("Times"), text="Geburtsdatum:")
        self.gatum.place(x=405,y=45)
        self.gatumf = Text(second_frame,height=1,width=10)
        self.gatumf.place(x=405,y=65)
        self.gatumfm = text="DEFAULT GEBURTSDATUM TEXT"
        
        self.gort = Label(second_frame,font=("Times"),text="Geburtsort")
        self.gort.place(x=505,y=45)
        self.gortf = Text(second_frame,height=1,width=11)
        self.gortf.place(x=505,y=65)
        self.gortfm = text="DEFAULT GEBURTSORT TEXT"
        
        self.pos = Label(second_frame,font=("Times"),text="Position:")
        self.pos.place(x=15,y=105)
        self.posf = Text(second_frame,height=1,width=20)
        self.posf.place(x=15,y=125)
        self.posfm = text="DEFAULT POSITION TEXT"
        
        self.bereich = Label(second_frame,font=("Times"),text="Bereich:")
        self.bereich.place(x=205,y=105)
        self.bereichf = Text(second_frame,height=1,width=20)
        self.bereichf.place(x=205,y=125)
        self.bereichfm = text="DEFAULT BEREICH TEXT"
        
        self.eint = Label(second_frame,font=("Times"),text="Eintrittsdatum:")
        self.eint.place(x=405,y=105)
        self.eintf = Text(second_frame,height=1,width=11)
        self.eintf.place(x=405,y=125)
        self.eintfm = text="DEFAULT EINTRITTSDATUM TEXT"
        
        self.aust = Label(second_frame,font=("Times"),text="Austrittsdatum:")
        self.aust.place(x=505,y=105)
        self.austf = Text(second_frame,height=1,width=11)
        self.austf.place(x=505,y=125)
        self.austfm = text="DEFAULT AUSTRITTSDATUM TEXT"
        
        #Befehle, um die Textfelder und alles andere im Fenster zu platzieren
        self.einleitung = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Einleitung")
        self.einleitung.place(x=15,y=165)
        self.Retter = Label(second_frame,font="1",text="Test")
        self.Retter.pack(padx=400,pady=1500)
        self.einleitungsf = Text(second_frame,height=3,width=60)
        self.einleitungsf.place(x=15,y=195)
        self.einleitungsfm = text="DEFAULT EINLEITUNGS TEXT"
        
        self.firmenbeschreibung = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold", text="Firmenbeschreibung")
        self.firmenbeschreibung.place(x=15,y=255)
        self.firmenbeschreibungf = Text(second_frame,height=3,width=60)
        self.firmenbeschreibungf.place(x=15,y=285)
        self.firmenbeschreibungfm = text="DEFAULT FIRMENBESCHREIBUNG TEXT"
        
        self.tätigkeit = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Tätigkeit")
        self.tätigkeit.place(x=15,y=345)
        self.tati1 = Text(second_frame,height=1,width=75)
        self.tati1.place(x=15,y=375)
        self.tati1m = text="DEFAULT TÄTIGKEIT1 TEXT"
        self.tati2 = Text(second_frame,height=5,width=75)
        self.tati2.place(x=15,y=395)
        self.tati2m = text="DEFAULT TÄTIGKEIT2 TEXT"
        
        self.fachwissen =Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Fachwissen")
        self.fachwissen.place(x=15,y=485)
        self.fachwissenf =Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.fachwissenf.place(x=15,y=515)#
        self.fachwissenfm = text="DEFAULT FACHWISSEN TEXT"
        
        self.leistungsbereitschaft = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Leistungsbereitschaft")
        self.leistungsbereitschaft.place(x=15,y=595)
        self.leistungsbereitschaftf = Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.leistungsbereitschaftf.place(x=15,y=625)
        self.leistungsbereitschaftfm = text="DEFAULT LEISTUNGSBEREITSCHAFT TEXT"
        
        self.arbeitsweise = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Arbeitsweise")
        self.arbeitsweise.place(x=15,y=705)
        self.arbeitsweisef = Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.arbeitsweisef.place(x=15,y=735)
        self.arbeitsweisefm = text="DEFAULT ARBEITSWEISE TEXT"
        
        self.arbeitsqualitat = Label (second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Arbeitsqualität")
        self.arbeitsqualitat.place(x=15,y=815)
        self.arbeitsqualitätf = Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.arbeitsqualitätf.place(x=15,y=845)
        self.arbeitsqualitätfm = text="DEFAULT ARBEITSQUALITÄT TEXT"
        
        self.belastungsfähigkeit = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Belastungsfähigkeit")
        self.belastungsfähigkeit.place(x=15,y=925)
        self.belastungsfähigkeitf = Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.belastungsfähigkeitf.place(x=15,y=955)
        self.belastungsfähigkeitfm = text="DEFAULT BELASTUNGSFÄHIGKEIT"
        
        self.führungsstil = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Führungsstil(nur bei leitenden Angestellten)")
        self.führungsstil.place(x=15,y=1035)
        self.führungsstilf = Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.führungsstilf.place(x=15,y=1065)
        self.führungsstilfm = text="DEFAULT FÜHRUNGSSTIL TEXT"
        
        self.gesamturteil = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Gesamturteil")
        self.gesamturteil.place(x=15,y=1145)
        self.gesamturteilf = Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.gesamturteilf.place(x=15,y=1175)
        self.gesamturteilfm = text="DEFAULT GESAMTURTEIL TEXT"
        
        self.soziales = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Soziales Verhalten")
        self.soziales.place(x=15,y=1255)
        self.sozialesf = Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.sozialesf.place(x=15,y=1285)
        self.sozialesfm = "DEFAULT SOZIALES VERHALTEN TEXT"

        self.aust = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Austrittsgrund")
        self.aust.place(x=15,y=1365)
        self.austf = Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.austf.place(x=15,y=1395)
        self.austfm = text="DEFAULT AUSTRITTSGRUND TEXT"

        self.absch = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Abschiedsformel")
        self.absch.place(x=15,y=1475)
        self.abschf = Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.abschf.place(x=15,y=1505)
        self.abschfm = text="DEFAULT ABSCHIEDSFORMEL TEXT"

        self.sonstiges = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Sonstige Zusätze und Formulierungen")
        self.sonstiges.place(x=15,y=1585)
        self.sonstigesf = Text(second_frame,height=4,width=40)
        self.sonstigesf.place(x=15,y=1615)
        self.sonstigesfm = text="DEFAULT SONSTIGES TEXT"

        self.vollständig = Label(second_frame,font="Times 15 bold",text="Vollständiger Arbeitszeugnis-Entwurf")
        self.vollständig.place(x=15,y=1815)
        self.vollständigf = Label(second_frame,font="Times 12 bold",text="Placeholder") #This line gets overwritten to have the output
        self.vollständigf.place(x=15,y=1895)
#A bunch of Labels and alike to make up the primary Window, where the input is gathered.
#There was a attempt at formatting, but it has yet to show any benefits.
#But the backstage doesn't have to look al that great.

        def saveFile():
            file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir="C:\\",
                                    defaultextension='.txt',
                                    filetypes=[
                                        ("Text file",".txt"),
                                        ("HTML file", ".html"),
                                        ("All files", ".*"),
                                    ])
            if file is None:
                return
            filetext = str(self.vollständigf.get(1.0,END))
            file.write(filetext)
            file.close()

 
        self.refresh= Button(second_frame, bg="white", text="Arbeitszeugnis erstellen", command=lambda: get_input())
        self.refresh.place(x=355,y=1600)
        self.save = Button(second_frame, bg="white", text="Speichern", command=lambda: saveFile())
        self.save.place(x=355,y=1630)
        

        
def _on_mouse_wheel(event):
    my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int((event.delta / 120)), "units")
    self.window_body = window_body
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = demo(root)
    root.geometry('1000x1000')
    root.mainloop()
```

I tried changing the approach but ultimately ended up back with this one again. Is there a way of telling the `saveFile` to take the contents of the label `self.vollständigf` and save that? I thought simply putting the `self.vollständigf` into

```
filetext = str(self.vollständigf.get(1.0,END))
```

would be enough, but I appear to be missing something.

Comment: `Label` does not have `.get()` so your code should fail to run.

Comment: The code runs until the `saveFile` is executed, but even then it doesnt crash, it just fails to save the file with the content I wanted. I tried
 replacing the `Label` with a `Text`, but the `Text` doesn't get `Text`. I haven't found an alternative to either `Label` or `Text` yet.

Comment: If `Label` does not have `.get()` to extract its text content, so how can you expect you can save it to file?

Comment: That is because it was the version of the code I had after I after trying to figure out work arounds. Previously I had used a  `Text` widget instead of `Label` but `Text` doesn't get to use the `Text` option. So I went onto attempting different Ideas but so far they failed aswell.

Comment: Try `filetext = self.vollständigf['text']` instead.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Comment: you have to provide a [mre] (with emphasis on _minimal_)